# My jmeter regex is not matching negative numbers

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a regex in jmeter which I want to match both positive and negative numbers. This is what I have at the moment, however it sets the variable to the default when the number is negative:

```
Reference Name: myVar
Regular Expression: ^-?\d+
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
Default value: 0
```

Can anyone tell me if there is something wrong with this? Thanks.

Comment: put this as `(^-?\d+)` and try

Comment: Where are these numbers: always at the start of the string? I doubt it but surely you need to define a capturing group if you use `$1$` template.

Comment: Probably not the problem, but you should escape `-` to `\-`.

Comment: There is no need escaping the hyphen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `([-]?\d+)` as a regular expression.

JMeter respects [Perl5-style regular expressions](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/regexps.html) so you can try searching for "perl regex" when you need a particular solution. Also see [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter User Manual.

By the way, you can test your regular expressions right in View Results Tree listener using "RegExp Tester" mode:

[image: RegExp Tester]

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) for more debugging tips and tricks

Comment: There is no need putting the hyphen into a character class as it is not a special regex metacharacter. Also, if there are float values this regex will match 5 and 56 in 5.56.

Comment: Removing braces around hyphen will result in `-5` when input is `5`. I agree with "floats" bit, thanks